# How to sum all instances of a number in a string in R

Tags: r

Lets say I have a string as follows

```
"The specimen is 34 x 1 x 5 mm and there is also another thing in there that is 22 x 4 x 1 mm and a further thing of 11 x 4 x 8 so this should be added together"
```

I want to add the cubic mm of each thing together and place in a separate field in my dataframe.

I have the regular expression to do this but I don't know how to capture every instance so I can add them together. The result should be `1226 mm3`

To capture one instance I use:

```
chunky <- str_extract(EndoSubsetEMRSizes$NatureOfSpec, "\\d+\\s*x\\s*\\d+\\s*x\\s*\\d+")
```

but how to capture all in the same string so they can be added?

Comment: I'm getting `610` by doing `sum(sapply(strsplit(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+ x \\d+ x \\d+", x))[[1]], " x ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) prod(as.integer(x))))`. Not sure how did you come up with `1226`

Comment: I get 610 as well... in a way more convoluted way.

Comment: Maybe add a reproducible example with several rows and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea with `rollapply` from `zoo` package,

```
library(zoo)
library(stringr)
sum(rollapply(as.numeric(str_extract_all(x, '[0-9]+')[[1]]), 3, by = 3, prod))
#[1] 610
```

or to apply it to a column,

```
sapply(EndoSubsetEMRSizes$NatureOfSpec, function(x)
          sum(rollapply(as.numeric(str_extract_all(x, '[0-9]+')[[1]]), 3, by = 3, prod))
```

Comment: are you missing commas or brackets from the column answer. Also Should the x after str_extract_all be EndoSubsetEMRSizes$NatureOfSpec

Comment: It is not missing anything... It should work as it is

Comment: Good use of `rollapply`

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
library(magrittr)
matrix(na.exclude(as.numeric(strsplit(x,split = "\\s")[[1]])),byrow = T,ncol = 3) %>% apply(.,MARGIN = 1,FUN = prod) %>% sum()
```

I am also getting `610` as answer.

Note : `Warning message` is due to the conversion of `numeric` mode.