# Summing instances in a string with variable instance number

Tags: r

I had asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38715162/how-to-sum-all-instances-of-a-number-in-a-string-in-r?noredirect=1#comment64810938_38715162) but don't seem to be able to get it to work for a similar situation.

I have a dataframe with a column such as (three separate rows):

```
There is some stuff here
There are 25 per hpf
There are 34 per hpf and there are 22 per hpf
There are between 23 per hpf, 12 per hpf and 15 per hpf
```

I want to extract into a separate column the largest of the numbers if a number is present before 'per hpf'

I have been hoping to do this with the following:

```
EoEDx$HPF<-sapply(EoEDx$HPF, function(x)
  sum(rollapply(as.numeric(str_extract_all(x, '[0-9]+per hpf')[[1]]), 3, by = 1, prod)))
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
Error during wrapup: wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

and I wonder if this is because I am pre-specifying the number of numbers to add- also how to get the max instead of the sum?

Comment: You want to *sum* or to *extract*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
sum(rollapply(unlist(sapply(str_extract_all(df1$HPF, "[0-9]+(?= per hpf)"),
                     as.numeric)), 3, by = 1, prod))
#[1] 46116
```

For extracting the largest numbers

```
as.numeric(sapply(str_extract_all(df1$HPF, "[0-9]+(?= per hpf)"), 
          function(x) x[which.max(as.numeric(x))][1]))
#[1] NA 25 34 23
```